# Using roots of irreducible polynomials to rewrite products.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $F$ is a field, and $p(x)\in F[x]$  is irreducible, of degree $n$, with a root $\alpha$.

"$F(\alpha)$ is closed under multiplication since $\alpha^n,\alpha^{n+1},\ldots $ can be written as combinations of $1,\alpha,\ldots, \alpha^{n-1}$ **using the equation $p(\alpha)=0$.**"

How is the latter equation being used? For example, if $F=\mathbb{Q},\alpha=\sqrt2, p(x)=x^2-2$, then how am I using the fact that $p(\sqrt2)=0$ when I rewrite $\sqrt2 ^5$ as $4\sqrt2$?

Comment: Whenever you have a $(\sqrt{2})^2$,you replace it with $2$. It's more easily seen if the polynomial has a different shape, say $x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What's more easily seen?

Comment: That you use the polynomial to replace $\alpha^n$ with a rational linear combination of lower powers of $\alpha$. With $(\sqrt{2})^2 = 2$, probably your intimate knowledge of the real numbers makes it hard to notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\alpha^2-2=0\implies \alpha^2=2\implies \alpha^3=\alpha(\alpha^2)=2\alpha\,,\,\alpha^4=(\alpha^2)^2=4\;,\ldots etc.$$

In general, if $\;a_0+a_1\alpha+\ldots+\alpha^n=0\;$ , then

$$\alpha^{n+1}=\alpha(\alpha^n)=\alpha(-a_0-a_1\alpha-\ldots-a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1})=$$

an expression of $\;1,\alpha,...,\alpha^n\;$ , and etc.